# Android - how to reset a TextView

Tags: android

I set an original TextView value like this:

```
TextView problemName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_variable);
```

But at some point I need to reset it to something new.  I don't see a function like setText() or anything like that.  How is the displayed text supposed to be reset?

Thanks!

Comment: There is a `setText()` method for a TextView. Make sure that you imported the correct `TextView`. `android.widget.TextView`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29) method for TextView.

Comment: thanks I must have been blind there for a bit not to notice it :)

Answer (score 2):

[textView.setText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and its overloads provide a way to change the value of the text. If you're looking to reset something else please elaborate in your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
problemName.setText("hhhjkbgjg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify if TextView on project set import android.widget.TextView;

android.widget.TextView have setText();